# CSS styling differs between local and deployed version on render.com

Tags: python, css, plotly-dash, render.com

I am in the process of creating an application using Plotly Dash and I'm looking to deploy it on render.com. As this is my first experience with deploying an application, I encountered some challenges along the way. However, I have managed to successfully deploy it. You can access the deployed app [here](https://tickery-xz4j.onrender.com/).

The issue I'm facing is that the CSS styling appears to be distorted. While some parts seem to be fine, others, such as the background color and the styling of elements like dropdown menus, are noticeably different from the local version. Initially, I only wanted to create a simple Dashboard, but I ended up adjusting CSS styling to make it look better, although I do not have any experience with it, so it is very possible that I screw up some fundamental rules. I am including a few screenshot comparisons for reference and also provided a link to the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Ravdar/tickery-dash-tools-deploy/tree/main).

[image]
[image]
[image]

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance. Thank you.